# Birt Rows to Columns + Break -> Row Duplication

Tags: birt

I have a data source based on a SQL SELECT statement that returns 2 rows with 4 columns:

attr_1,attr_2,attr_3,attr_4
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8

I create a BIRT report where the columns in the select are written as rows in a table. The table breaks after each source row.

Attribute 1 - 1
Attribute 2 - 2
Attribute 3 - 3
Attribute 4 - 4

Attribute 1 - 5
Attribute 2 - 6
Attribute 3 - 7
Attribute 4 - 8

My layout is :

[image]

With this setup I nearly get what I want. The column data is displayed in the rows and a break occurs after the last column/row. But each source row from the SELECT statement is appearing twice duplicating the output.

Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had bindings at the List and Table level. Removing the table level bindings fixed the problem.